# Docker get previous image with FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible with Docker to get a previous version of Docker image(not the current one), for example:

```
FROM base:previous
```

or something like this. Unfortunately, I don't know this image digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `previous` is the tag of the image. If you know the tag of the older image just write that.

As an example the official mysql image (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) lists several tags ranging from 5.5 to 8.0

So I can start an instance of mysql 5.5 using

```
docker run mysql:5.5
```

You could also do that in your Dockerfile, if the older version is 1.0 you would do:

```
FROM base:1.0
```

If you don't know which tag you used previously you might be able to find it if you list all your images locally

```
docker images
```

Good luck!